# YouTube channel video player with playlist

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am looking for creating youtube section on my site, where the user could plug in their "youtube channel name" and it will show a playlist/player box on their profile.

What I want in this playlist/player box is that it should play the default video on load; the list of other videos in the channel could be on the left side or on the bottom.
Clicking on another video will start playing that video.

I know there are lot many widget and tools available for doing but I am not getting the specific thing that I am looking for.
Can anyone point me to a proper page/tutorial to do this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, it's super easy with Linq. Just consume the YouTube video feed and then do whatever you want with it:

Here's the call you make to get the list of videos from a channel:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/YOUTUBE_USERNAME_HERE/uploads?orderby=updated

And here's some example code:

```
    var url = FeedUrl;
    XDocument rss = XDocument.Load(url);

    var videos = from i in rss.Root.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
            select new
            {
                Title = i.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title").Value,
                URL = i.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link").Attribute("href").Value
            };
```

You can do what you want with the feed at that point, such as convert the video URLs into something embeddable, and so forth.

Good luck!

Best,

-Auri